# Why am I getting - "Cannot call API for app 439150000328651 on behalf of user 1245010195894306"

Tags: api, facebook

This error message was generated right after a scheduled post on Heropost failed to upload. We are just an end user of Heropost and we are not the developer. We were suggested to raised this to the attention of the community.

#heropost #problemsseen8yearsago #hopingthatthiscanbefound

Comment: If Heropost has that problem they need to fix it. There is nothing anyone else can do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.